# PHP MySQL Highscore table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Im joining 3 tables to present a table with users highest score

**My tables**

game_log:

```
 ---ID---user_ID---score---time---
 |   1      52      567     10   |
 |   2      53      641     13   |
 |   3      52      465     8    |
 |   4      53      451     14   |
 ---------------------------------
```

users:

```
 ---ID---name---countyid---
 |   52  Dave      1      |
 |   53  John      2      |
  ------------------------
```

county:

```
  ---countyid---countyname---
  |      1    Orange wichit |
  |      2    Orange clemts |
   --------------------------
```

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM game_log 
INNER JOIN users ON game_log.user_ID=users.ID 
INNER JOIN county ON users.countyid=county.countyid 
ORDER BY game_log.score DESC , game_log.time LIMIT 20";
```

Above code gives me this result:

```
Rank---Name--------County------Score---Time
1      John     Orange clemts   641     13
2      Dave     Orange wichit   567     10
3      John     Orange clemts   465     8
4      Dave     Orange wichit   451     14
```

My problem is that I want the highscore table to display the top 20 users with the highest score, not the 20 highest scores.

Like this:

```
Rank---Name--------County------Score---Time
1      John     Orange clemts   641     13
2      Dave     Orange wichit   567     10
```

Need som help with this, not familiar with joining tables ;-)

Comment: Join with a subquery wich selects the max score for each group.

Comment: Which record do you want brought back for a user if they have 2 instances of the same score, and that score is the highest for them, and they are in the top 20? The one with the lowest or highest time value? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach will show the top 20 users and each user's highest score, and if they have multiple instances of the same score, it'll show the information for the earliest one (lowest time value for that user and score).

```
SELECT *
  FROM game_log gl
 INNER JOIN users u
    ON gl.user_ID = u.ID
 INNER JOIN county c
    ON u.countyid = c.countyid
 WHERE not exists (select 1
          from game_log gl2
         where gl2.user_id = gl.user_id
           and gl2.score > gl.score)
   and not exists (select 1
          from game_log gl2
         where gl2.user_id = gl.user_id
           and gl2.time < gl.time
           and gl2.score = gl.score)
 ORDER BY gl.score DESC, gl.time LIMIT 20;
```

Without doing this, if the same user in the top 20 had the same score 2+ times, they would be listed 2+ times, and you would not get back 20 people by using LIMIT 20 because the same person would be taking up N rows out of that 20.

SQL Fiddle here showing data with a tie: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ac931/5/0

Answer (score 2):

[`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) should do the job.

```
SELECT users.ID, users.name, county.countyname, MAX(game_log.score) AS score, game_log.time
FROM game_log
INNER JOIN users ON game_log.user_ID = users.ID
INNER JOIN county ON users.countyid = county.countyid
GROUP BY game_log.user_ID
ORDER BY game_log.score DESC, game_log.time
LIMIT 20;
```

Try it out with [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/510b5d/1).

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with the `not exists` approach to get the highest score for each user.  The rest of the query is the same:

```
SELECT *
FROM game_log gl INNER JOIN
     users u
     ON gl.user_ID = u.ID INNER JOIN
     county c
     ON u.countyid = c.countyid
WHERE not exists (select 1
                  from game_log gl2
                  where gl2.user_id = gl.user_id and gl2.score > gl.score
                 )
ORDER BY gl.score DESC, gl.time
LIMIT 20;
```

The `where` clause is saying "keep this row if no other row for the same user has a higher score".

Another way to do this is with the aggregation approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM (select user_id, max(score) as maxscore
      from game_log gl
      group by user_id
     ) gl INNER JOIN
     users u
     ON gl.user_ID = u.ID INNER JOIN
     county c
     ON u.countyid = c.countyid
ORDER BY gl.maxscore DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

But this method loses the information about `time`.  It is possible to include that, but it makes the query more complicated.